# pygithub - Receive all commits of a specific branch

Tags: python, github, pygithub

I am using pygithub for analyzing repositories and iterating on all commits of a repository. But how can I extract the corresponding branch for each commit?

```
commits = repo.get_commits()
for commit in commits:
     # print(commit.branch) ... something in this way
```

Many thanks for your help!

Sebastian

Comment: did you try the get_branch method ? 
You have also an url param in the repo.get_commits() method....did you try to apply your complete url wit the branch like so : `github.com/YOUR_ACCOUNT/YOUR_REPO/tree/BRANCH_NAME`

Comment: Hi yAzou, after some investigation I found that:
+ `get_branches` provides a list of all branches but those provide only a reference on the HEAD
+ `html_url` of a commit does not contain any branch information but only the SHA.
Any other ideas?

Comment: And did you try with the url parameters in repo.get_commits() ?
https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/github_objects/Repository.html?highlight=commits#github.Repository.Repository.get_commits

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand. The signature of `get_commits()` looks in the following way:  `get_commits(sha=NotSet, path=NotSet, since=NotSet, until=NotSet, author=NotSet)`. How to integrate a url?

Comment: I mean the path params....
like so :
get_commits(path="tree/YOUR_DESIRED_BRANCH_NAME")

Comment: Many thanks for your patience! I evaluated the following:

```
    branches = repo.get_branches()
    for branch in branches:
        print(branch.name)
        commits = repo.get_commits(path="tree/"+branch.name)
        for commit in commits:    
            print(commit) 
```

But I received only on commit per branch? What's wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212499/discussion-between-poseidonius-and-yazou).

Comment: Could you share you answer please I have the same problem.

Comment: Hi SebNik, at the end I identified all occurring branches and iterate them step by step. At the end every commit referenced the branches in which it appears.

Comment: @Poseidonius after you managed to get the paginated list of commits, are you able to iterate over it? i've got the paginated list but i can't seem to iterate