# pygithub how to get latest commit on specific branch

Tags: commit, git-branch, pygithub

Using pygithub how to get latest commit on specific branch in a repo
equivalent to github rest api https://{github.com}/api/v3/repos/{repo/}/{org}/commits/{branch}?per_page=1
I followed the steps mentioned in
[pygithub - Receive all commits of a specific branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61430485/pygithub-receive-all-commits-of-a-specific-branch) , It's returning null.

`branches = repo.get_branches() for branch in branches: print(branch.name) commits = repo.get_commits(path="tree/"+branch.name) for commit in commits: print(commit)`

Answer (score 0):

Considering [`PyGithub/PyGithub` issue 1967](https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub/issues/1967), try `get_commit` or `branch.commit`, first, for a single branch:

```py
branches = repo.get_branches()
  for branch in branches:
    print("branch.last_modified: " + str(branch.last_modified))
    print("branch.commit: " + str(branch.commit))
    HEAD = repo.get_commit( str(branch.commit.sha))
```